# What is M , L , XAML for Path Data attribute

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I am looking at an in-house Silverlight control to make some changes to it and I see something like;

```
 <Path x:Name="SomeIcon" Data="M102.03442,598.79645 L105.22962,597.78918
```

...copied just a part of what was in the Data.

What are those? How did they know what to put there? Also, what do they affect?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That's called the [**Path Markup Syntax**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and it's used to define the shape of a Path.

- `M` represents the `Move` command, which moves the "current location" to the specified point in X,Y.
- `L` represents the `Line` command, which draws a line from the current location to the specified point in X,Y.

You can type it manually, though it is recommended that you use a Vector graphics capable editor, such as [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/).

Comment: so in my case, the control is a radio button and you know that little circle inside a radio button that shows up when we "Select" a radio button? Do you think this is responsible for drawing that?

Comment: Generally it's just an `Ellipse` inside the control template that becomes visible on the IsChecked=True state invoked by the VisualStateManager, nothing to complex.

Answer (score 4):

M stays for "move" and L stays for "Line". Is a language to draw a geometry and it is called [Stream geometry mini-language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As stated before, think like driving a plotter, M moves with the pen up, L down the pen and move with the pen down, very simple. A a little geometry knowledge is enough to create something interesting, even if some tools can help ypu, as Expression Blend.